# Склонение названия села

Tags: склонение

Как правильно:село Абатское, у села Абатского, селу Абатскому за селом Абатским.

Или село Абатское, у села Абатское, к селу Абатское, за селом Абатское

Я считаю правильным первый вариант. Оба слова склоняются.

Answer (score 2):

В соответствии с общелитературной нормой (особенно в деловой, географической литературе, туристических справочниках) такие топонимы не склоняются: у села Арбатское, но в разговорной речи склонение допускается: у села Арбатского.

Также: под деревней Видное, но: у горы Магнитной, под сопкой Ключевской.

Дополнение

На склоняемость топонимов ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО могут действовать различные факторы: совпадение рода (чаще склоняется), известное название большого города (чаще склоняется), название маленького села в центральной прессе (не склоняется).

Во всем этом просматривается общее правило: донести до читателя правильное название, не исказив его при склонении.

Answer (score 1):

См. http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_90 :

> Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями
>   город, **село**, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции
>   приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется,
>   если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет
>   собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование.
>
> Правильно: *в городе Москве, в городе Санкт-Петербурге, из города
>   Киева; в деревню Ивановку, из деревни Ольховки, **в селе Шушенском**,
>   под хутором Михайловским...*

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы: склоняются оба слова. Род нарицательного существительного и топонима совпадает (село Арбатское).

Однако в современном русском языке бнаруживается тенденция к несклоняемости приложений-топонимов среднего рода, оканчивающихся на -е, -о: ***между селами Молодечно и Дорожно, недалеко от села Миронежье, в городе Видное.***